# Replace part of line above N lines of given search pattern

Tags: regex, bash, replace, awk

I have a file containing my Nagios hosts in which i need to change some hosts parents and i'm pretty clueless on how to tackle this problem with a script.

The file is located on a freebsd server and i'm using bash as my prefer'd shell.

The structure of the file looks like this:

```
define host{
use                    template-here
name                   testname
alias                  testalias
check_command          check-host-alive
max_check_attempts     5
contact_groups         group1
parents                parent1.abc.local   //2. Change this line
notification_interval  240
notification_period    none
notification_options   d,r
register               0
}

define host{
host_name              host2234.abc.local  //1. Search for this line
address                10.10.10.5
notification_period    07-21
use                    testname
}
```

The only pattern i can be 100% sure about and search the file for is the host_name line, it always contains 4 numbers.

If i do a grep, "grep -B10 -m1 2234.abc file" i can be a 100% sure that i'll get the correct parent for the host i'm searching for included in the result, and this is where I'm stranded. 
How do i proceed with changing the parent in the result of my grep and then saving the new value for the parent to the file. And putting all this in a loop since it's more than one host i need to change the parent on.

An output of the actual grep above looks like this:

```
grep -B10 -m1 2234.abc stack
max_check_attempts     5
contact_groups         group1
parents                parent1.abc.local
notification_interval  240
notification_period    none
notification_options   d,r
register               0
}

define host{
host_name              host2234.abc.local
```

A second example of another host in the same file with additional lines in it and has the same parent that is to be changed as the first example.

```
grep -B10 -m1 2235.abc stack
contact_groups         group2
parents                parent1.abc.local
notification_interval  240
notification_period    none
notification_options   d,r
register               0
active_checks_enabled  1
}

define host{
host_name              host2235.abc.local
```

To avoid any confusion, it is not possible for me to just replace the entire string on the parent line through out the file since I'm not moving all the hosts connected to the current parent.

I have several other similar use cases  where the same logic applies so I'd be more than happy if someone could give me a knudge in the right direction, get the wheels spinning as to speak, rather than just post a complete solution. 
Well, unless this is a duplicate of a thread i could not find while searching and googling.

Thanks!

Update with result from Ed Mortons script, it only prints the contents of the file without changing the line:

```
root@workdawg:script # cat tst.awk 
BEGIN { RS=""; ORS="\n\n" }
/2234\.abc/ { sub(/parents[^\n]+/,"parents\t\t\t*** Eureka! ***",prev) }
NR>1 { print prev }
{ prev = $0 }
END { print prev }
root@workdawg:script # awk -f tst.awk  stack
define host{
use                    template-here
name                   testname
alias                  testalias
check_command          check-host-alive
max_check_attempts     5
contact_groups         group1
parents                parent3.abc.local
notification_interval  240
notification_period    none
notification_options   d,r
register               0
}

define host{
host_name              host2234.abc.local
address                10.10.10.5
notification_period    07-21
use                    testname
}
```

Comment: Is there always a line break in between each block?

Comment: Usually yes, but not always. 
Some hosts might have an additional check as well but searching for 10 lines above the hostname will always get the parent line.

Comment: Please supply a sample output, it makes it so much easier to cook up a script. -- Preferably with a second example, in which things are different.

Comment: If i understood correctly i've added output and a second example in original question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't show your expected output so it's a guess but is this what you want?

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { RS=""; ORS="\n\n" }
/2234\.abc/ { sub(/parents[^\n]+/,"parents\t\t\t*** Eureka! ***",prev) }
NR>1 { print prev }
{ prev = $0 }
END { print prev }

$ awk -f tst.awk file
define host{
use                    template-here
name                   testname
alias                  testalias
check_command          check-host-alive
max_check_attempts     5
contact_groups         group1
parents                 *** Eureka! ***
notification_interval  240
notification_period    none
notification_options   d,r
register               0
}

define host{
host_name              host2234.abc.local  //1. Search for this line
address                10.10.10.5
notification_period    07-21
use                    testname
}
```

The above reads each blank-line-separated block of text (courtesy of `RS=""`) one at a time and always prints the record before the most recent one read. If the current record contains `2234.abc` then the `sub()` replaces the `parent` line in the previous record before printing it.

Comment: Youve got it right! This is exactly what i want to do. 
This does not work for me though, nor on my actual conf or on the example below.  Version of my awk is 4.1.1.

Comment: Ed Morton, I've updated my original question with the output of your script.

Comment: A long time later, I'm finally back to mark your answer as the solution. 
I had to clean up the entire conf as it was a total mess with space mixed with tabs and newlines all over the place.

Answer (score 0):

There are definitely a number of ways to do this..This example uses a bash script with `grep -n` and `sed` to do the job:

```
#!/bin/sh
file="whatever.conf"
# Get the line numbers from the text
find_grep_line_number() {
  local line_txt=$1
  local x
  i=0

  # Isolate the line number from grep -n before the :
  local REG_EX="^(.*):"
  if [[ $line_txt =~ $REG_EX ]]
  then
    local n=${#BASH_REMATCH[*]}
    for (( x=0; x<$n; x++ ));
    do
      #echo "$x: ${BASH_REMATCH[$x]}"
      i=${BASH_REMATCH[$x]}
    done
  fi
}

line_host_txt=`grep -n "^host_name" $file`
find_grep_line_number $line_host_txt
host_line=$i
line_parents_txt=`grep -n "^parents" $file`
find_grep_line_number $line_parents_txt
parents_line=$i

replacement_parents_line="parents                parent1.abc.local"
# Replace the parents line with a new line.
rslts=`sed -i "$parents_line c\$replacement_parents_line" $file`
```

I didn't test this script but it should work (LoL).. `sed` is great for doing these sorts of things (http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/unix-linux-sed-match-replace-the-entire-line-command/)

Comment: sed is absolutely the wrong tool for jobs like this which is why you need a relatively large shell script to try to support it and the end result is very fragile. awk is 100% the right tool for it but it's not tagged with awk so I doubt if many awk experts will look at it and I'm feeling lazy. shell is just to sequence calls to tools and sed is only the right tool for simple substitutions on a single line, for anything else you should be using the UNIX general purpose text manipulation tool - awk.

Comment: GoinOff, thanks for the answer. This one works partly, no matter what i search the file for, it changes the first line in the file that contains the "parent", not the parent connected to the host i search for.

Comment: I fixed the grep lines to look for lines that start with `parents` instead of a global line search. `"^parents"` and `"^host_name"` are new.  Give it a try and see if that helps.